# What is the irreducible Brillouin zone for a rhombic unit cell?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, photonics

So I realised that the rhombic unit cell is in fact not the same as a hexagonal unit cell. (I thought they both gave hexagonal lattices but the rhomic unit cell with two rods gives a honeycomb lattice wheras hexagonal unit cell with one rod gives a hexagonal lattice). Since photonic band diagrams are normally sweeping along the path of the irreducible Brillouin zone, I was wondering, how do I find the irreducible Brillouin zone of a rhombic unit cell?

Answer (score 4):

First, the reciprocal lattice vectors $\bar a,\bar b,\bar c$ can be calculated from the direct space lattice vectors $a,b,c$ via ([Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice)):
$$
\bar a = 2\pi \frac{b\times c}{a\cdot(b\times c)}
$$
(equivalently $\bar b$ and $\bar c$ by cyclic permutation of $a,b,c;~$ i.e. $~\bar b=2\pi (c\times a)/[b\cdot (c\times a)]$.)

The next step is to consider neighboring lattice points in reciprocal space connected by $\bar a,\bar b,\bar c$ and to lay normal planes on the midpoints of the corresponding connecting lines (i.e. a [Wigner-Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) [or [Voronoi cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_cell)] is constructed in reciprocal space).

This Brillouin zone could be reduced further depending on the point group symmetry of the lattice (e.g. parts of the reciprocal space Wigner-Seitz cell could be rotated or mirrored on top of each other).

Below is an example of a hexagonal cell in direct space (left subplot), and the corresponding Wigner-Seitz cell in reciprocal space (right subplot; plots created with [XCrySDen](http://www.xcrysden.org/)).

[image: Hexagonal unit cell in direct spave and corresponding Wigner-Seitz cell in reciprocal space]

The Wigner-Seitz cell in reciprocal space corresponding to the hexagonal cell in direct space is also a hexagonal cell.

Here is an example of a rhombohedral cell in direct space and the corresponding Wigner-Seitz cell in reciprocal space:

[image: Rhombohedral unit cell in direct spave and corresponding Wigner-Seitz cell in reciprocal space]

Depending on the point group of your system, the irreducible Brillouin zone will only be a wedge of the Wigner-Seitz cell.